# How can i add click event on bars in horizontal funnel chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How can I add click event on funnel bar in amcharts.

```
am4core.ready(function () {
    debugger;

    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.SlicedChart);
    chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

    chart.data = [{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "The first",
        "value": 600
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "The second",
        "value": 300
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "The third",
        "value": 200
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "The fourth",
        "value": 180
    }, {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "The fifth",
        "value": 50
    }, {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "The sixth",
        "value": 20
    }, {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "The seventh",
        "value": 10
    }];    
});
```

and looking to perform click event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chartdiv").on("click", function () {
        $("#id-133").click(function () {
            console.log("clicked on ");
        });
    });
});
```

Here I am doing by Id which is wrong because of Id change dynamically. 
Is there any click event in amcharts?

Answer (score 1):

Get my answer by doing

```
 am4core.ready(function () {

    // Themes begin
    am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
    // Themes end

    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.SlicedChart);
    chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0;

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.FunnelSeries());
    series.colors.step = 2;
    series.dataFields.value = "value";
    series.dataFields.category = "name";
    series.dataFields.id = "id";
    series.alignLabels = true;
    series.orientation = "horizontal";
    series.bottomRatio = 1;

    series.data = [{
        "id": 10,
        "name": "The first",
        "value": 600
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "The second",
        "value": 300
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "The third",
        "value": 200
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "The fourth",
        "value": 180
    }, {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "The fifth",
        "value": 50
    }, {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "The sixth",
        "value": 20
    }, {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "The seventh",
        "value": 10
    }];

    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    chart.legend.position = "top";

    series.slices.template.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.target.dataItem.id);
        console.log(ev.target.dataItem._dataContext);
    });

});
```